# Organizar array multidimensional em javascript, evitando que o próximo item tenha o mesmo tipo do anterior

Tags: javascript, array, array-multidimensional

Estou com um problema de lógica aqui. Vamos ver se vocês podem ajudar, pois to queimando neurônios aqui e não encontrei um ponto de partida.

Eu tenho uma array de objetos e preciso organizar ela de uma forma que o item anterior não possa ser igual ao próximo item. Algo assim

```
var result = [
    {  type: 'image',  name: 'foo image', src: 'http://www.something.com/path/to/image.jpg', text: "lorem ipsum sit amet" },
    {  type: 'video',  name: 'foo video', src: 'http://www.something.com/path/to/video.mp4', text: "lorem ipsum sit amet" },
    {  type: 'text',  name: 'foo text', src: '', text: "lorem ipsum sit amet" },
    {  type: 'text',  name: 'foo text', src: '', text: "lorem ipsum sit amet" },
    {  type: 'text',  name: 'foo text', src: '', text: "lorem ipsum sit amet" },
    {  type: 'video',  name: 'foo video', src: 'http://www.something.com/path/to/video.mp4', text: "lorem ipsum sit amet" },
    {  type: 'image',  name: 'foo image', src: 'http://www.something.com/path/to/image.jpg', text: "lorem ipsum sit amet" },
    {  type: 'text',  name: 'foo text', src: '', text: "lorem ipsum sit amet" },
    {  type: 'video',  name: 'foo video', src: 'http://www.something.com/path/to/video.mp4', text: "lorem ipsum sit amet" }
];
```

Do jeito que está, ao ser exibido na tela, mostrará 3 blocos seguidos do tipo `text` na interação da array. Seria necessário fazer uma interação, para equilibrar ao máximo os items, pra não deixar dois blocos seguidos de texto. Claro que a array pode vir entupido de itens do tipo `text` ou só com eles, não podendo intercalar direito, mas isso não vem ao caso agora.

Do item acima, o resultado teria que ficar algo assim:

```
var result = [
    {  type: 'image',  name: 'foo image', src: 'http://www.something.com/path/to/image.jpg', text: "lorem ipsum sit amet" },
    {  type: 'video',  name: 'foo video', src: 'http://www.something.com/path/to/video.mp4', text: "lorem ipsum sit amet" },
    {  type: 'text',  name: 'foo text', src: '', text: "lorem ipsum sit amet" },
    {  type: 'video',  name: 'foo video', src: 'http://www.something.com/path/to/video.mp4', text: "lorem ipsum sit amet" },
    {  type: 'text',  name: 'foo text', src: '', text: "lorem ipsum sit amet" },
    {  type: 'image',  name: 'foo image', src: 'http://www.something.com/path/to/image.jpg', text: "lorem ipsum sit amet" },
    {  type: 'text',  name: 'foo text', src: '', text: "lorem ipsum sit amet" },
    {  type: 'video',  name: 'foo video', src: 'http://www.something.com/path/to/video.mp4', text: "lorem ipsum sit amet" }
    {  type: 'text',  name: 'foo text', src: '', text: "lorem ipsum sit amet" }
];
```

Alguém já passou por essa situação? Toda ajuda será bem vinda :)

PS: repetir no sentido que o próximo item pode ser um tipo `image` ou `video`, mas não pode ter 2 `text` seguidos (salvo situação onde não tenha como organizar por ter só texto ou muitos textos)

Comment: Alguma resposta ajudou a resolver o problema e pode sanar dúvidas similares de outros usuários? Caso positivo não esqueça de marcar a resposta como aceita. Pra fazer isso é só clicar no ✓ do lado esquerdo da mesma (abaixo do indicador de up e down votes).

Answer (score 1):

Levando a solução apenas pelo lado da lógica eu faria o seguinte:

- Separaria o `array` principal organizando pelos tipos em outros `arrays` menores;
- Verificaria qual teve o maior número de ocorrências;
- Percorreria os `arrays` menores até o final ou até a quantidade observada anteriormente, intervalando pelas chaves;
- Adicionaria em um `array` final;

O código ficaria da seguinte forma:

```js
var result = [
    {  type: 'image',  name: 'foo image', src: 'http://www.something.com/path/to/image.jpg', text: "lorem ipsum sit amet" },
    {  type: 'video',  name: 'foo video', src: 'http://www.something.com/path/to/video.mp4', text: "lorem ipsum sit amet" },
    {  type: 'text',  name: 'foo text', src: '', text: "lorem ipsum sit amet" },
    {  type: 'text',  name: 'foo text', src: '', text: "lorem ipsum sit amet" },
    {  type: 'text',  name: 'foo text', src: '', text: "lorem ipsum sit amet" },
    {  type: 'video',  name: 'foo video', src: 'http://www.something.com/path/to/video.mp4', text: "lorem ipsum sit amet" },
    {  type: 'image',  name: 'foo image', src: 'http://www.something.com/path/to/image.jpg', text: "lorem ipsum sit amet" },
    {  type: 'text',  name: 'foo text', src: '', text: "lorem ipsum sit amet" },
    {  type: 'video',  name: 'foo video', src: 'http://www.something.com/path/to/video.mp4', text: "lorem ipsum sit amet" }
];

var organizador = {};
var tamanhoMaximo = 0;
var final = [];

result.forEach(function(item) {
  // Garante a criação do tipo no array organizador
  if (!organizador.hasOwnProperty(item.type)) {
    organizador[item.type] = [];
  }

  organizador[item.type].push(item);
});

// Percorre o objeto pra saber o item de maior tamanho
for (var type in organizador) {
  var tamanho = organizador[type].length;
  
  if (tamanho > tamanhoMaximo) {
    tamanhoMaximo = tamanho;
  }
}

// Percorre os arrays
for (var indice = 0; indice < tamanhoMaximo; indice++) {
  // Percorre as chaves
  for (var type in organizador) {
    if (indice < organizador[type].length) { // Verifica se o array tem item neste índice
      final.push(organizador[type][indice]); // Adiciona ao resultado final
    }
  }
}

document.write(JSON.stringify(final, null, 2));
```

**Resultando em:**

```
[
  { "type": "image", "name": "foo image", "src": "http://www.something.com/path/to/image.jpg", "text": "lorem ipsum sit amet" },
  { "type": "video", "name": "foo video", "src": "http://www.something.com/path/to/video.mp4", "text": "lorem ipsum sit amet" },
  { "type": "text", "name": "foo text", "src": "", "text": "lorem ipsum sit amet" },
  { "type": "image", "name": "foo image", "src": "http://www.something.com/path/to/image.jpg", "text": "lorem ipsum sit amet" },
  { "type": "video", "name": "foo video", "src": "http://www.something.com/path/to/video.mp4", "text": "lorem ipsum sit amet" },
  { "type": "text", "name": "foo text", "src": "", "text": "lorem ipsum sit amet" },
  { "type": "video", "name": "foo video", "src": "http://www.something.com/path/to/video.mp4", "text": "lorem ipsum sit amet" },
  { "type": "text", "name": "foo text", "src": "", "text": "lorem ipsum sit amet" },
  { "type": "text", "name": "foo text", "src": "", "text": "lorem ipsum sit amet" }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Podes fazer isso em dois passos: organizar por chaves, e depois intercalar. No final limpas as posições vazias com `.filter(Boolean);`.

O código seria assim:

```
// agrupar por chaves
var tipos = original.reduce(function(obj, entrada) {
    if (!obj[entrada.type]) obj[entrada.type] = [];
    obj[entrada.type].push(entrada);
    return obj;
}, {});
// ficas com {image: [...], video: [...], text: [...]}

// intercalar
var resultado = Object.keys(tipos).reduce(function(arr, tipo, i, _tipos){
    let entrada, pos = 0 + i, qtd = _tipos.length;
    // posicionar de espaçados por "qtd" de tipos, começando pelo index do tipo em Object.keys(tipos)
    while (entrada = tipos[tipo].shift()){
        arr[pos] = entrada || null;
        pos+= qtd;
    }
    return arr;
}, []).filter(Boolean);
```

#### Exemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/4mnxfkra/